# jCarousel Lite visible frame HTML showing only on mouse move in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I have an HTML slideshow done using jCarousel Lite, running in auto mode, showing one li at a time, each frame containing few pictures and some text, all nicely dressed in HTML and CSS.

Everything works perfectly in FF, Chrome, IE8, Safari and Opera, but in IE7 (well, IE8 actually running in IE7 mode) only 1 picture (the first one) of each frame is displayed, and everything else is... well, not visible. Not there. Somewhere else.

The funny part is that it is enough to just move a mouse anywhere over the page, and all missing elements (in all frames) appear at this very moment.

And here is where I'm dumbfounded. Why? What the heck is going on there? Has anyone faced such a problem (or even similar) before?

Answer (score 1):

CSS problem with css of jCarousel Lite is using div's position:relative, if your image/text inside jCarousel Lite's div also using div with attribute position then those image/text will not show.

Maybe you can try to add attribute width for your frame which contain your pictures & text.